# firebase_auth/invalid-credentials The supplied auth credential is incorrect, malformed or has expired?

Tags: flutter, firebase

I'm creating a flutter application and when i provide the data to the sign in with email and password functionality in firebase this error popup which is auth credential is firebase_auth/invalid-credentials The supplied auth credential is incorrect, malformed or has expired i searched alot but there is no solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I used to get the same error when I tried to authenticate a user.
Ensure your Firebase configuration matches the requirements of your project.

Try going to the Firebase console -> Authentication -> email and password sign-in enabled.

Comment: void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  return runApp(
    const ProviderScope(
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

Comment: it's already enabled in firebase console unfortunately the problem still exist and i don't know why this is my code on the top for my configuration